# Clear 1 Item in a player's inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I added a command block which tests if a player has a gold_nugget, followed by a comparator. That comparator leads to a command block which gives you 1 ladder, and also to another command block which clears 1 gold_nugget. But it won't clear it.

The command I used:

```
/clear @p minecraft:gold_nugget 1
```

Answer (score 4):

`/clear`'s syntax:

```
/clear <player> [id] [Damage] [maximum amount] {dataTags}
```

You have the "1" stated as the "Damage". You'll need to shift it over by specifying the "Damage" (which would be 0 for gold nuggets):

```
/clear @p minecraft:gold_nugget 0 1
```

Comment: @desdevil you should mark it as answered if this fixed your problem

Comment: I still don't understand what is the "damage" number stuff...